# Is ZBar unable to recognize colored barcodes?

Tags: python-3.x, zbar

I am using **ZBar** (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) in one of my project and I noticed that the library is unable to recognize barcodes if they are colored: let's say yellow background, and blue foreground (the bars). The application requires to have colored barcodes when impressed on a paper label.

Is there a way to trick the issue, or is there another library that make this thing possible?

NOTES: I am using Python 3.7.1 for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Zbar processes pictures in black and white, so it would be possible to edit the pictures so that they recognize the QR code better. You could edit the image so that the pixels differ from white to a certain percentage, black. All the other Prxel you dye white. Darduch would have to give a good contrast.

Here possible formula, as an example:

```
(R/255*100)>6||(G/255*100)>6||(B/255*100)>6
```

How big the deviation must be, you have to test.